# wsgi.py error after migrating GAE app to Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I've just come to Python from PHP after inheriting a legacy google app engine app. I've tried migrating to python 2.7 following various online tutorials, but I'm way out of my depth with the error below. Is it something to do with how I'm calling the GAE or Django api?

```
...
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

builtins:
- remote_api: on

inbound_services:
- warmup


libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"  
...
```

I still have

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
```

In my code, should this be changed to a builin?

```
ERROR    2012-02-28 16:31:00,167 wsgi.py:205] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-        default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line     193, in Handle
    result = handler(self._environ, self._StartResponse)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_1_2/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 248, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_1_2/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 141, in get_response
    return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resolver' referenced before assignment
INFO     2012-02-28 16:31:00,178 dev_appserver.py:2884] "GET /ibi/index.html HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `run_wsgi_app` in Python 2.7 runtime. In your `app.yaml` you have to refer to the actual WSGI application object.

See [documentation here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27.html#Django) on how to properly configure Django

Comment: Thanks, I had missed that in the docs. I'll give it a go tomorrow.